# Thanking someone

Tags: vocabulary, archaicisms

I have two questions:

1. *Does thank you* become archaically *thank thee*?
2. Are there alternative ways, archaic or not, of saying *thank you* other than *thanks*?

Comment: [Presumably](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt25a29.htm) yes to the first -- see verse 13.

Comment: 1. _Thank you_ is a set phrase; the subject is missing, but _I_ or _we_ is implicit. I'm not sure if there is such a set phrase with _thee_, so I'd rather bet on _I thank thee_ or _we thank thee_. 2. http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/ways-of-saying-thank-you

Comment: Archaically/dialectally it's ***Thank 'ee*** (presumably shortened from *I/We thank **ye***) when the subject is missing. If the subject *was* present, it would have been *I thank thee* in "relatively" informal contexts (I don't think it would normally have been "proper" for a commoner to address nobility as ***thee***).

Answer (score 2):

In answer to your second point:

There aren't enough ways to say 'Thank you'; however there are a few, mostly informal, ways below. My favourites being 'I'm very much obliged', 'you've been too kind' and 'I'm most grateful for your efforts.'

> - **hat tip** noun
>     something that you say, especially when writing on the Internet, to show that you are grateful to someone for giving you information
> - **shout-out** noun
>     informal a public statement of thanks
> - **thank you** interjection
>     used for telling someone that you are grateful for something that they have said or done
> - **bless you**
>     used when you want to thank someone
> - **much obliged**
>     used for thanking someone politely
> - **cheers** interjection
>     British informal thank you
> - **ta** interjection
>     britishinformal thank you
> - **I owe you one**
>     used for thanking someone for something that they have done for you
> - **you’re too kind/generous**
>     used for thanking someone in a way that is very polite but not completely sincere
> - **thanks** noun
>     things that you say or do to tell people that you are grateful to them

[macmillan dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/ways-of-saying-thank-you)